# Loading chunks around the player

Tags: java, loading, game-engine, chunks

I am making a Voxel Engine in Java. I have the chunk system working, but I am concerned that I am not loading the chunks in the most efficient way possible.

My chunks are stored inside a Hash Map, like so:

```
Map<Vector2f, Chunk> chunkList = new HashMap<Vector2f, Chunk>(); // Create an array for the chunks
```

This way I have a 2D Array of chunks and can access them like so:

```
chunkList.get(new Vector2f(0, 0));
```

This is how I load all the chunks around the player:

```
public void updateChunks( Vector3f cameraPosition ) { // Update all the chunks

    Thread chunkThread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            int playerChunkX = (int) Math.floor(cameraPosition.x / ( Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * BlockVertices.BLOCK_SIZE )); // Get the current chunk that the player is in on the X - Axis
            int playerChunkZ = (int) Math.floor(cameraPosition.z / ( Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * BlockVertices.BLOCK_SIZE )); // Get the current chunk that the player is in on the Z - Axis

            System.out.println( playerChunkX + ", " + playerChunkZ );

            for (int i = 0; i < Camera.view_distance; i++) { // X - Axis iteration
                for (int j = 0; j < Camera.view_distance; j++) { // Z - Axis iteration
                    if( !(chunkList.containsKey( new Vector2f( playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ ) ) )) { // If the chunk manager doesn't have a chunk at the specified location

                        chunkList.put(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ), new Chunk(perlin, playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ)); // Create a new chunk
                        chunkList.get(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ)).load(); // Load the new chunk

                    }

                    if (!(chunkList.containsKey(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ + j)))) { // If the chunk manager doesn't have a chunk at the specified location

                        chunkList.put(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ + j), new Chunk(perlin, playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ + j)); // Create a new chunk
                        chunkList.get(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ + j)).load(); // Load the new chunk

                    }

                    if (!(chunkList.containsKey(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ - j)))) { // If the chunk manager doesn't have a chunk at the specified location

                        chunkList.put(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ - j), new Chunk(perlin, playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ - j)); // Create a new chunk
                        chunkList.get(new Vector2f(playerChunkX + i, playerChunkZ - j)).load(); // Load the new chunk

                    }

                    if (!(chunkList.containsKey(new Vector2f(playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ - j)))) { // If the chunk manager doesn't have a chunk at the specified location

                        chunkList.put(new Vector2f(playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ - j), new Chunk(perlin, playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ - j)); // Create a new chunk
                        chunkList.get(new Vector2f(playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ - j)).load(); // Load the new chunk

                    }

                    if (!(chunkList.containsKey(new Vector2f(playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ + j)))) { // If the chunk manager doesn't have a chunk at the specified location

                        chunkList.put(new Vector2f(playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ + j), new Chunk(perlin, playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ + j)); // Create a new chunk
                        chunkList.get(new Vector2f(playerChunkX - i, playerChunkZ + j)).load(); // Load the new chunk

                    }

                }
            }

        }

    };
    chunkThread.run();

}
```

As you can see, I am using a seperate thread for this, for better performance.
Is there a better way of doing this?
If so, what is the **most efficient** way to load chunks around the player?

Comment: The **best** way is opinion based. The rest of your question is *code review*, for which there exists another site. Do you have a concrete programming question that would be on-topic for SO? Furthermore, do not apply premature optimization. Have you maesured the actual impact of using seperate threads? I'd probably only use *one* background loading thread, and enqueue the stuff sequential.

Comment: By **best** I meant the most efficient. Mistake on my part, I'll edit the question. Currently the extra thread does increase the FPS in the game by 10-20%, but it should be more significant once I add more stuff to the chunks. However, I never meant for this to be a code review. I posted my solution to this problem, but I don't think this is the most efficient way to do this, hence, this post.

Comment: There is no single best solution. It too much depends on the specifics of your game, e.g. how often the player goes back-and-forth between chunk boundaries. Furthermore, programming isn't about finding the best solution, its about finding solutions that *work reasonably wel*+. if you always try to find the "best" solution (by whatever metric that might be, try to come up with an objective metric for "good" solutions first, its difficult), you will never get anything done.

Comment: I can't disagree on that. You are completely right. I'll just go with whatever works until I find a better solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this way that thread should be always in execution, to "observe" the player movement.

I don't know if for you it's possible, but I would suggest to switch the control on the movement itself, in this way you may avoid this thread in while(true) loop.
So, punctually executing the calculation to load the chunks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood you fully. Are you suggesting that I call this only when the player moves?

Comment: Yep. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes I can. I didn't think of that before. It does improve some things. Do you think this code would be efficient? There is a lot of checking and for loops included, which causes concerns about the actual efficiency of loading chunks this way.

Comment: You should look at the camera position and recalculate the chunks only when it is more than a certain threshold from the last position where you recalculated. You could also consider using an octree approach to quickly prune the search space rather than iterating over every possible chunk.

Comment: I love that. I'll only update the chunks once the player moves a specified amount :) As for octrees, I have been doing some reading, and I don't think they would be good for my Voxel Engine. Modifying a voxel would require a lot of work and would be slower than just a normal array of blocks. If I were to use the octree for the chunks, I'm not sure how well it would work, since I constantly load new chunks, meaning I would have to add a lot of points to the tree. Since this topic is new to me, I may be wrong on this, so please correct me if I am wrong :)